# SQL 2014 Stored Procedure Insert into table where table check is null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I want to have run on a daily basis. I have a constraint in the stored procedure that it cannot insert data into the table if the current date equals the maximum date in the table like so:

```
-- MAKE SURE IT WAS NOT RUN FOR THE DAY ALREADY
AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)
```

During testing, I truncated the table. When I executed the sp `exec smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt_sp;` and then checked the resultant table for data it was blank. So I ran the `INSERT` query that runs if the table is already created and sure enough got no results and I found that it was definitely because of the aforementioned line.

How would I correct this? If I for some reason truncate the table in the future (which really should not happen...but)

Here is the sp in it's entirety if needed:

```
/*
Check to see if the table even exists. If not create and populate, else insert
new records only if the run date is not already in the table.
*/
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='c_ins_bal_amt' AND xtype='U'
)


BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt (
        PK INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
        , pt_id char(13) NOT NULL
        , unit_seq_no int NULL
        , cr_rating VARchar(2) NULL
        , vst_end_date date NULL
        , fc VARchar(4) NULL
        , hosp_svc char(4) NULL
        , Age_In_Days Int NULL
        , pyr_cd varchar(6) NOT NULL
        , pyr_seq_no int NOT NULL
        , tot_chg_amt money NULL
        , tot_enc_bal_amt money NULL
        , ins_pay_amt money NULL
        , pt_bal_amt money NULL
        , Ins_Bal_Amt money NULL
        , tot_pay_amt money NULL
        , pt_pay_amt money NULL
        , GuarantorDOB date NULL
        , GuarantorFirst varchar(30) NULL
        , GuarantorLast varchar(60) NULL
        , ins1_pol_no varchar(20) NULL
        , ins2_pol_no varchar(20) NULL
        , ins3_pol_no varchar(20) NULL
        , ins4_pol_no varchar(20) NULL
        , RunDate date NOT NULL
        , RunDateTime datetime NOT NULL
        , RN INT
    )

INSERT INTO smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt

SELECT PYRPLAN.pt_id
, VST.unit_seq_no
, VST.cr_rating
, CAST(VST.vst_end_date AS date)                     AS [vst_end_date]
, VST.fc
, VST.hosp_svc
, CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, VST.VST_END_DATE, GETDATE()) AS int) AS [Age_In_Days]
, PYRPLAN.pyr_cd
, PYRPLAN.pyr_seq_no
, CAST(VST.tot_chg_amt AS money)                     AS [tot_chg_amt]
, CAST(VST.tot_bal_amt AS money)                     AS [tot_enc_bal_amt]
, CAST(VST.ins_pay_amt AS money)                     AS [ins_pay_amt]
, CAST(VST.pt_bal_amt AS money)                      AS [pt_bal_amt]
, CASE
    WHEN PYRPLAN.PYR_CD = '*' THEN 0
    ELSE CAST(PYRPLAN.tot_amt_due AS money)
    END                                                AS [Ins_Bal_Amt]
, CAST(VST.tot_pay_amt AS money) AS [tot_pay_amt]
, CAST((VST.tot_pay_amt - VST.ins_pay_amt) AS money) AS [pt_pay_amt]
, CAST(guar.GuarantorDOB as date)                    AS [GuarantorDOB]
, guar.GuarantorFirst
, guar.GuarantorLast
, vst.ins1_pol_no
, vst.ins2_pol_no
, vst.ins3_pol_no
, vst.ins4_pol_no
, [RunDate] = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
, [RunDateTime] = GETDATE()
, [RN] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY PYRPLAN.PT_ID
    ORDER BY PYRPLAN.PYR_SEQ_NO
)

FROM SMSMIR.PYR_PLAN AS PYRPLAN
LEFT JOIN smsmir.vst_rpt VST
ON PYRPLAN.pt_id = VST.pt_id
        AND PYRPLAN.unit_seq_no = VST.unit_seq_no
LEFT JOIN smsdss.c_guarantor_demos_v AS GUAR
ON VST.pt_id = GUAR.pt_id
    AND VST.from_file_ind = GUAR.from_file_ind

WHERE VST.tot_bal_amt > 0
AND VST.vst_end_date IS NOT NULL
AND VST.fc not in (
    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
)

ORDER BY PYRPLAN.pt_id
, PYRPLAN.pyr_cd
END

ELSE
    INSERT INTO smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt
    SELECT PYRPLAN.pt_id
    , VST.unit_seq_no
    , VST.cr_rating
    , CAST(VST.vst_end_date AS date)                     AS [vst_end_date]
    , VST.fc
    , VST.hosp_svc
    , CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, VST.VST_END_DATE, GETDATE()) AS int) AS [Age_In_Days]
    , PYRPLAN.pyr_cd
    , PYRPLAN.pyr_seq_no
    , CAST(VST.tot_chg_amt AS money)                     AS [tot_chg_amt]
    , CAST(VST.tot_bal_amt AS money)                     AS [tot_enc_bal_amt]
    , CAST(VST.ins_pay_amt AS money)                     AS [ins_pay_amt]
    , CAST(VST.pt_bal_amt AS money)                      AS [pt_bal_amt]
    , CASE
        WHEN PYRPLAN.PYR_CD = '*' THEN 0
        ELSE CAST(PYRPLAN.tot_amt_due AS money)
        END                                                AS [Ins_Bal_Amt]
    , CAST(VST.tot_pay_amt AS money) AS [tot_pay_amt]
    , CAST((VST.tot_pay_amt - VST.ins_pay_amt) AS money) AS [pt_pay_amt]
    , CAST(guar.GuarantorDOB as date)                    AS [GuarantorDOB]
    , guar.GuarantorFirst
    , guar.GuarantorLast
    , vst.ins1_pol_no
    , vst.ins2_pol_no
    , vst.ins3_pol_no
    , vst.ins4_pol_no
    , [RunDate] = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
    , [RunDateTime] = GETDATE()
    , [RN] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY PYRPLAN.PT_ID
        ORDER BY PYRPLAN.PYR_SEQ_NO
    )

    FROM SMSMIR.PYR_PLAN AS PYRPLAN
    LEFT JOIN smsmir.vst_rpt VST
    ON PYRPLAN.pt_id = VST.pt_id
            AND PYRPLAN.unit_seq_no = VST.unit_seq_no
    LEFT JOIN smsdss.c_guarantor_demos_v AS GUAR
    ON VST.pt_id = GUAR.pt_id
        AND VST.from_file_ind = GUAR.from_file_ind

    WHERE VST.tot_bal_amt > 0
    AND VST.vst_end_date IS NOT NULL
    AND VST.fc not in (
        '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
    )
    -- MAKE SURE IT WAS NOT RUN FOR THE DAY ALREADY
    AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)

    ORDER BY PYRPLAN.pt_id
    , PYRPLAN.pyr_cd
;
```

Comment: so your problem is that (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt) can return NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you want the stored proc to do if you somehow truncate the table in the future. If you just want the SP to stop then just add a check into the stored proc at the beginning

```
 If Not Exists (Select * from smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt) return 0
```

If on the other hand, you want it to ignore the date constraint, put the same condition into the date constraint logic:

```
WHERE VST.tot_bal_amt > 0
   AND VST.vst_end_date IS NOT NULL
   AND VST.fc not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
  -- MAKE SURE IT WAS NOT RUN FOR THE DAY ALREADY
   AND (Not exists(Select * from smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)Or
         CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != 
           (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) 
            FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt))
```

or, alternatively:

```
WHERE VST.tot_bal_amt > 0
   AND VST.vst_end_date IS NOT NULL
   AND VST.fc not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
  -- MAKE SURE IT WAS NOT RUN FOR THE DAY ALREADY
   AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != 
           CAST(coalesce(
              (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt), 
               getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, although the alternative you present returns no results because the coalesce date brings back the same as getdate()

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right than after the truncate the check `(SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)` will return null

That means you are actually doing this :

```
AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != NULL
```

And you cannot compare NULL using !=
So adjust your check like this

```
AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) <> convert(date, isnull((SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt), getdate() - 1))
```

This way you are always checking on a valid date, even it your table is trucated

Answer (score 1):

```
AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != (SELECT isnull(MAX(RUNDATE), '19000101') FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to check to see if there are any records in that table:

```
AND 
(
    CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != (SELECT MAX(RUNDATE) FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)
OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt)
)
```

`RUNDATE` is already defined as `NOT NULL`, so just looking for the existence of records in the table would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an ISNULL around the date check with a dummy date:

```
    AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date) != isnull((SELECT MAX(RUNDATE)
    FROM smsdss.c_ins_bal_amt) , '7/4/1776')
```